# JSON to hashed value

Tags: javascript, json

I was wondering if anyone knew of a quick library or some solution which basically does this.

```
code({ json: 1 }) -> codedsecret

decode(codedSecret) -> { json: 1 }
```

Basically, I'm looking for a way to translate JSON to an encoded string that most folks won't be able to understand for security reasons.

Comment: Perhaps [Crypto JS](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/)? (with all the usual caveats about client-side security)

Comment: Yeah I just saw that, might work well thanks

Comment: You can reverse your string :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If by "most folks" you mean non-sneaky developers, then base64 is probably sufficient.  Modern browsers should implement `btoa` and `atob` (both directions), but there are libraries out there in case you need more compatibility.

```
var secret = btoa(JSON.stringify({json: 1}));
JSON.parse(atob(secret)); // {json: 1}
```

This offers no cryptographic security at all and is easily cracked by developers who can recognize and even decode base64 strings visually.  If you need to cover those two circumstances, then you need to look into encrypting on the server side before communicating with the client and vice versa.  There are OpenSSL implementations for JavaScript, but I'm not sure how much I'd trust them.

Comment: That works also, I don't think I need a lot of security at the moment (mostly used to filter out obvious stuff about what is going on). If someone figures out what I'm storing it's not a game changer.